# Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_10

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am wanting to multiply  `2*tf.Variable(4.0)` but it gives me an error

```
a3dim = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],
                  [[5,6],[7,8]]
                 ])

print("a3dim Shape: ", a3dim.shape)

tf_t=tf.convert_to_tensor(a3dim,dtype=tf.float64)
tf3=tf.Session()
gt =  2*tf.Variable(4.0)
init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
tf3.run(init)


with sess.as_default():
  tf3.run(2*tf.Variable(4.0))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1364     try:
-> 1365       return fn(*args)
   1366     except errors.OpError as e:

6 frames
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_10
     [[{{node Variable_10/read}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1382                     '\nsession_config.graph_options.rewrite_options.'
   1383                     'disable_meta_optimizer = True')
-> 1384       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1385 
   1386   def _extend_graph(self):

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_10
     [[node Variable_10/read (defined at <ipython-input-40-47f6d514f317>:2) ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have received `FailedPreconditionError`, which means you running an operation that read a variable before it has been initialized.

To fix above issue, you can perform  `multiply op` outside of session and resolve its value inside the session. Please refer working code shown below in `TF 1.x`

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x

import tensorflow as tf

mlt= 2*tf.Variable(4.0)

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
     init= tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
     sess.run(init)
     print(sess.run(mlt))
```

In `TF 2.x`, eager execution enabled by default, working code shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
gt =  2*tf.Variable(4.0)
print(gt)
```